# How to determine which region contains the biggest area of an intersected region in Android?

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas

I want to write a rotating radial menu similar to the one inside this photo

[image: photo]

I managed to draw the View and drew the wedges using the [Path](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html) class

Right now I am trying to determine which Wedge is selected by the Selection Wedge(The red colored one)

[image: Wedges]

I tried to get the regions of all the wedges inside the View and tried to check for the intersection and union but it is not working as from the following photo

[image: Rects]

The selection region intersects 3 different regions at the same time and if I tried the union operation it will return false as the selection region is not completely inside the chosen region.

So I thought of choosing the Wedge that contains the biggest area of the selection region, But I don't know how.

Any help would be appreciated.

If anyone has a better solution or suggestion I will gladly hear it and apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head: How about arbitrarily reducing the region of the selection wedge by 50% (or whatever was needed) in each dimension prior to checking it for intersection with the menu wedges? The drawn selection wedge would stay the same, you'd just reduce its region dimensions after you got them.

Comment: I got your Idea, and it is correct but I guess the problem is that when I rotate the canvas the regions are not rotated with it, so the selection is fixed and always the same .